# Allow editors access to added plugins

Tags: user-roles, editor

I created a custom plugin which i want Users who are Editors to be able to use the plugin.

I found a link here to allow access for editors to allow editors to edit menus[allow editors to edit menus?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4191/allow-editors-to-edit-menus)

using this code.

```
    $role_object = get_role( 'editor' );

// add $cap capability to this role object
$role_object->add_cap( 'edit_theme_options' );
```

So, is there a possible way i can allow Editors access to my custom added plugins

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please add the following code.

```
function activate_plugin_name() {
   $role = get_role( 'editor' );
   $role->add_cap( 'manage_options' ); // capability
}
// Register our activation hook
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_plugin_name' );

function deactivate_plugin_name() {

  $role = get_role( 'editor' );
  $role->remove_cap( 'manage_options' ); // capability
}
// Register our de-activation hook
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivate_plugin_name' );`
```

Refer my tutorial for further explanation.
http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/user-role-editor-access-wordpress-plugins/

Answer (score 3):

After a quick search, i got my answer here

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-allow-non-admins-editors-authors-to-use-certain-wordpress-plugins

By changing all occurances of 'manage_options' to 'edit_pages' in my Plugins files.

Editors are allowed to use plugins with Edit_pages

Comment: I tried your suggestion but did not worked for me.

Can you give more details of how to accoplish that?, please

Comment: Okay, do you need a sample Plugin code snippet on Github? That should work

Comment: exactly ! it works like a charm thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is just a use case of a need to activate a plugin for "editor" user role. The plugin is called [bulk images to posts](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-images-to-posts/). This plugin is active only for admin role. So to activate it for "editor" role, you have to go through the "bulk-images-to-posts.php" file and search for big_create_menu() function (responsible of creating a menu in the left admin bar)
**Now if you replace "manage_options" by "edit_pages"** you will see that in "editor" role admin menu, the plugin becomes active.
**Again this is just an example of 1 use case to show the effect of "edit_pages"**

Here is a code snippet showing this:

```
// create new top-level menu
global $bip_admin_page;
$bip_admin_page = add_menu_page(__('Bulk Images to Posts Uploader','bulk-images-to-posts'), __('Bulk','bulk-images-to-posts'), 'edit_pages', 'bulk-images-to-post','bip_upload_page','dashicons-images-alt2');
// create submenu pages
add_submenu_page( 'bulk-images-to-post', __('Bulk Images to Post - Upload','bulk-images-to-posts'), __('Uploader','bulk-images-to-posts'), 'edit_pages', 'bulk-images-to-post');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Liz Eipe for [your solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/108014/liz-eipe-c), but unfortunately that did not work for me. What did work for me, was changing the 'capability' for all the [add_menu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) and the [add_submenu_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) hooks.

Basically the capability value you set, corresponds to access for different types and combinations of users. You can view all the possible capabilities and their access [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/).

I choose 'publish_posts' as value, which gives Super Admin, Admin, Editor and Author access to the admin page you register with your hooks.

This was my code before:

```
add_menu_page(
  'My Menu Title',
  'custom menu',
  'administrator', // Only a admin access
  'myplugin/myplugin-admin.php',
  '',
  plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ),
  3
);
```

And now with Admin, Editor and Author access it's changed to:

```
add_menu_page(
  'My Menu Title',
  'custom menu',
  'publish_posts', // Admin, Editor, Author access
  'myplugin/myplugin-admin.php',
  '',
  plugins_url( 'myplugin/images/icon.png' ),
  3
);
```

One last small note; do not forget to change this for all the plugin admin pages you want other users to have access to, like all the submenu pages.